# Drag and Drop: How to identify target item entry?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, drag-and-drop

I successfully realized Drag and Drop between two `DataGrids`, i.e. the target `DataGrid` knows which entries of the source `DataGrid` where selected and can use them for further processing.

Now I would like to identify the entry of the target `DataGrid` where the mouse have been placed for the drop. Is this possible and if yes, how can I achieve this?

Below my target `DataGrid` code:

```
void TargetList_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  var mySourceRecords =
    e.Data.GetData(typeof(List<MySourceRecord>))
    as List<MySourceRecord>;

  // Process selected vehicle variants
  ... mySourceRecords should be processed here with the target DataGrid record ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can perform a hit test using `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest`

```
Point targetPoint = e.GetPosition(DataGrid1);
HitTestResult result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(DataGrid1, targetPoint);
DependencyObject dropTarget = result.VisualHit;
```

you can perform a hit test on datagrid using `InputHitTest` to identify where the drop was made

```
Point targetPoint = e.GetPosition(DataGrid1);
IInputElement dropTarget = DataGrid1.InputHitTest(targetPoint);
```

after these methods dropTarget will be the one where the drop was made. now you can identify the target by couple of methods.

by finding the datacontext if the element is a frameworkelement or by finding appropriate parent's datacontext.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it appears the target should be the sender, depending on how you setup the drag and drop. That is:

```
    void TargetList_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var target = (FrameworkElement) sender;
    }
```

However, you may be subscribing to drop on the data grid rather than its visual children so the above may not work for you.

The attached behavior below may help solve your problem. I have been using it for years. You simple set IsDragSource on the element that will be draggable and IsDropTarget on the element that can receive drops. I usually use MVVM so I added a DropCommand so that it is the view model that handles the drop.

```
public static class DragAndDropManager
{
    #region IsDragSource Attached Property

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDragSourceProperty
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsDragSource",typeof(bool),typeof(DragAndDropManager),new PropertyMetadata(IsDragSourceChanged));

    public static void SetIsDragSource(DependencyObject d, bool value)
    {
        d.SetValue(IsDragSourceProperty, true);
    }

    public static bool GetIsDragSource(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (bool)d.GetValue(IsDragSourceProperty);
    }

    private static void IsDragSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = d as FrameworkElement;
        if (element == null)
            return;

        element.PreviewMouseMove += OnPreviewMouseMove;
    }

    private static void OnPreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        var element = (FrameworkElement)sender;

        var dragSource = args.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;

        if (args.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed
            || dragSource == null
            || dragSource.DataContext == null)
            return;

        var dragData = new DataObject(dragSource.DataContext);
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(element, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IsDropTarget Attached Property

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDropTargetProperty
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsDropTarget",typeof(bool),typeof(DragAndDropManager),new PropertyMetadata(IsDropTargetChanged));

    public static void SetIsDropTarget(DependencyObject d, bool value)
    {
        d.SetValue(IsDropTargetProperty, true);
    }

    public static bool GetIsDropTarget(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (bool)d.GetValue(IsDropTargetProperty);
    }

    private static void IsDropTargetChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = d as FrameworkElement;
        if (element == null)
            return;

        element.AllowDrop = true;
        element.DragOver += OnDragOver;
        element.Drop += OnDrop;
    }

    private static void OnDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data == null || e.Handled)
        {
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
            return;
        }

        var element = (FrameworkElement)sender;

        var command = GetDropCommand(element);
        if (command == null)
            return;

        var dataFormats = e.Data.GetFormats();
        if (dataFormats==null)
            return;

        var dragAndDropInfo = new DragAndDropInfo(element.DataContext,
                            e.Data.GetData(dataFormats.FirstOrDefault()));

        var canDrop = dragAndDropInfo.DroppedItem != dragAndDropInfo.SourceItem
                        && command.CanExecute(dragAndDropInfo);

        e.Handled = true;

        e.Effects = canDrop
                    ? e.Effects = DragDropEffects.All
                    : DragDropEffects.None;
    }

    private static void OnDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data == null || e.Handled)
            return;

        var element = (FrameworkElement)sender;

        var command = GetDropCommand(element);
        if (command == null)
            return;

        var dataFormats = e.Data.GetFormats();
        if (dataFormats == null)
            return;

        var dragAndDropInfo = new DragAndDropInfo(element.DataContext,
                            e.Data.GetData(dataFormats.FirstOrDefault()));

        var canDrop = dragAndDropInfo.DroppedItem != dragAndDropInfo.SourceItem
                       && command.CanExecute(dragAndDropInfo);

        if (canDrop)
        {
            command.Execute(dragAndDropInfo);
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }

    #endregion

    #region DropCommand Attached Property

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DropCommandProperty
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DropCommand",typeof(ICommand),typeof(DragAndDropManager),new PropertyMetadata(DropCommandProperty));

    public static void SetDropCommand(DependencyObject d, ICommand value)
    {
        d.SetValue(DropCommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static ICommand GetDropCommand(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (ICommand)d.GetValue(DropCommandProperty);
    }

    #endregion
}


public class DragAndDropInfo
{
    public object SourceItem { get; private set; }
    public object DroppedItem { get; private set; }

    public DragAndDropInfo(object sourceItem, object droppedItem)
    {
        SourceItem = sourceItem;
        DroppedItem = droppedItem;
    }
}
```

}

Sample XAML below for a TreeView example. In your case you can do something similar on a row presenter, etc

```
<TreeView
  Behaviors:DragAndDropManager.IsDropTarget="true"
  Behaviors:DragAndDropManager.DropCommand="{Binding DropCommand}">
  <TreeView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
      <Style.Setters>/>
        <Setter Property="Behaviors:DragAndDropManager.IsDragSource" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Behaviors:DragAndDropManager.IsDropTarget" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Behaviors:DragAndDropManager.DropCommand" Value="{Binding DropCommand}"/>
      </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
  </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```